# How can I programmaticaly change variables in a Word document using C++?

Tags: c++, ms-word

I have a Word document which is a template, and inside this document I whish to have some variable fields. Through my program I want to change these values on demand (e.g. calling Word and passing some parameters to it using a C++ program). I've searched a lot but so far I couldn't find good examples of that.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word has a proprietary file format which I imagine will be incredibly tricky to parse programmatically (i.e. by opening the file using an `fstream`).

If you are keen on using Microsoft products, your best bet may be to use Microsoft Access (a database manager), insert the data you want as a row in some database, and then create some formatted form which uses this data and generates a printable document for you. Here's a useful link: [Create Form in Microsoft Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-form-in-access-5d550a3d-92e1-4f38-9772-7e7e21e80c6b)

Comment: _"Microsoft Word has a proprietary file format which I imagine will be incredibly tricky to parse programmatically"_ This hasn't been true for more than a decade. (Read about DOCX.)

Comment: That being said, your suggestion of Access is much closer to a suitable solution for the OP's needs.